# Updating a table based on the results of another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables - one is an account table and the other is an appeal table. Both are joined by `Account_Id`.

The Account table has a unique person_code, account_id (one `person_code` can have multiple `account_ids` which can also have more than one `status_code`), status codes of 1,2,3.

The Appeal table has `account_id` and `hearing_date` (can be multiple hearing dates for each `account_id`).  I need to get the maximum `hearing_date` less than 01-JAN-2014 from the appeal table, where whichever max hearing date corresponds with the status code of '1' from the account table `status_code`.

Example:

Account table:

```
person_id: 1234     account_id: 57897      status_code: 1
person_id: 1234     account_id: 65098      status_code: 2
person_id: 4567     account_id: 90455      status_code: 2
person_id: 4567     account_id: 98567      status_code: 1
```

Appeal table:

```
account_id: 57897     hearing_date: 12-FEB-2014
account_id: 65098     hearing_date: 22-JAN-2014
account_id: 90455     hearing_date: 22-JAN-2015
account_id: 98567     hearing_date: 22-FEB-2014
```

I need to do an update statement so that the max `hearing_date` in the appeal table  (where the `hearing_date` is < 01-JAN-2014)  where that `account_id` has a `status_code` of 1 in the account table is updated to another `status_code`.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can guide me as I'm trying case statements and sub queries and I'm not getting anywhere fast :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not a 'get your work done for free' service. Please show what you have tried, so we can help you find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite follow what you need but here's the rough idea:

```
update Accounts
set accounts_column = (
    select max(hearing_date)
    from Appeals
    where Appeals.Account_Id = Accounts.Account_Id /* <- the important part */
        and hearing_date < '20140101'
)
where status_code = 1
```

Comment: Shawnt00 - thank you for helping me on this. The end result was:     UPDATE accounts a
SET    a.status_code = '2'
WHERE  a.status_code = '1'
AND EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 
         FROM appeals h
        WHERE h.account_id = a.account_id
          AND h.hearing_date < to_date('01-JAN-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
          AND h.hearing_date = (SELECT MAX(h2.hearing_date)
         FROM appeals h2
        WHERE h2.account_id = a.account_id));